# How to log server successful and unsuccessful attempts of a web service authentication by usernameToken using WSS4j

Tags: authentication, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

How can I log on server successful and unsuccessful attempts of a web service authentication by usernameToken using WSS4j?
As I understand checking login/password accordance takes place inside WSS4j and if authentication was successful web service's method is called and otherwise it is simply not called

Answer (score 0):

With username token there are two cases:

Plain text password and password digest.

In the plain text password case you have complete control over authentication of the request. This is because, authentication is carried out by the callback handler implementation provided by you as the developer. The callback handler implementation will authenticate the incoming username/password pair against the stored values depending on your implementation. Therefore you will be able to log successful and unsuccessful attempts.

However, in the password digest case, the callback handler is implemented by you to feed WSS4J with the password of the incoming username. In this case WSS4J computes the password digest value and does the authentication. In this case you don't have the above control to log the result at the callback handler.